# How do I get JSON data and then place it inside another variable without having to worry about Future method

Tags: flutter, dart

In my use case, I have to change the layout of the app with JSON data. I have a JSON file which I want to get and use the key values without using the Future method in the next method rather I want to place the mapped JSON and place it in empty curly brackets:

This is the JSON file I grab:

```
# test_json.json

{
"fontSize" : "10",
"fontFamily" : "A",
"fontWeigth" : "bold",
"fontColor" : "blue"
}
```

This is the file that grabs the JSON file and maps it:

```
# get_json.dart


class GetJson{
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getJson() async {
    String jsonData =
        await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/test_json.json');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonData);
    return data;
  }


}
```

Then I grab this mapped JSON and I want to place it inside a variable called `mappedData` and place it inside empty curly brackets.  Then I want to get the number with `getNumber()` and inside this method I convert the type of `fontSize` from string to double with another custom method called `TypeConvertor.getDouble()`:

```
class Utility {
  var mappedData= {};

 setJson() async {
    mappedData = await GetJson().getJson();
  }

getNumber(String key) {
    var data = mappedData;
    return TypeConvertor.getDouble(data[key]);
  }
}
```

In my use case, i need to do this like this I have no other choice. I want to explicitly grab the JSON like that and I don't want `getNumber()` to be a Future. Then i cannot place `Utility().getNumber("fontSize")` inside a stateful widget because then I have to use `setState` and I want to avoid that because I will have a lot of keys beside `fontSize` and so then I have to use `setState` for every key values. I just want to use `Utility().getNumber("fontSize")` inside property `fontSize` and The rest also like this. In my usecase I have to do it like that:

```
class TestView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestView> createState() => _TestViewState();
}

class _TestViewState extends State<TestView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      "test",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: Utility().getNumber("fontSize")),
    );
  }
}
```

But in my app `mappedData` gives null. The full error is : `Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'` and the null value is inside `mappedData`. I want to grab the json data and place it inside an empty map and use the mapped json from there on. How do i resolve the null execption issue?

**EDIT**

Change variables to correct versions

Comment: You might want to change the value in your json file from "10" to 10 (remove the quotes), since it's considered a String, which might prevent the `getDouble` function not to work as expected

Comment: That function works i have tested it, its just that i get `null`. I have to use `"10"` in my usecase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it's because you don't call `setJson` before call `getNumber`.
The following code is work.

```dart
final utility = Utility();
await utility.setJson();
print(utility.getNumber("fontSize"));
```

If you want to avoid similar mistakes, you have some options as solutions.

- Include `mappedData` to Utility's constructor.
- Change `getNumber` to static, and add argument `mappedData`.
- **Use [JsonSerializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable)(It's a little difficult but the best solution.)**

Comment: I comment on my answer. Because my reputation is low so I can't comment on the answer by @StudentOfFlutter.

I felt a little sad because the entire code appeared for the first time in your answer.
I thought that I answered your question perfectly (and provided very quite useful additional information)...

Anyway, congratulation solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which is partly contributed by @bakatsuyuki. So i did use `await utility.setJson();` but i also initilized it with `initState()` so field `utility` has no `null` value. I also used `FutureBuilder()` to check if `snapshot.hasData` and then i display the `Text()` widget with the data from `utilitiy` else show empty `Container`. This way i can resolve the `null` Exception.

This is the view that worked for me:

```
class AppView extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppView({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppViewState createState() => _AppViewState();
}

class _AppViewState extends State<AppView> {
  final utility = Utility();

  Future setUtility() async {
    await utility.setJson();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    setUtility();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder(
            future: AppContent().getAppContent(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text("test",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: utility.getNumber("fontSize"),
                    ));
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```